# Getting HibernateException : The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: The internal connection pool has reached its maximum size and no connection is currently available! I believe the problem is due to incorrect session handling. Can anyone suggest the correct way?

This is my Service class.

```
@Service
public class DataService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public User createUser(User newUser) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(newUser);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return newUser;
    }

    public User findUser(UUID userId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            return session.get(User.class, userId);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my Hibernate Configuration. I think my configuration is correct. My Session instantiation and closing in-service class is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rest_database?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

        <mapping class="com.in.models.User" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are closing your sessions in your `DataService` so you could be running out of connections.

Comment: @locus2k I updated the class, but still getting the same error. I have a DB Query browser connected to my database, so in my configuration there is only 1 allowed connection and the query browser is already connected. Is it because of that, it is running out of connections?

Comment: You have a poolsize of 1. Also your code is flawed in case of an error in `createUser` you are leaking a session and thus connection.

Answer (score 0):

In my *hibernate.cfg.xml* connection pool size was 1.

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

My db query browser(DBeaver) was already connected to my database, hence when I was trying to save the object, it was giving the hibernate exception - no connection available.

When I increased the connection pool size to 2 in *hibernate.cfg.xml*. Exception got resolved, as database allowed 2 connections.

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>
```

Comment: Good catch. One caveat.  Hiberates `connection.pool_size` shouldn't be used in a production environment according to their own api. Should remove the value and use a 3rd party like dbcp that you're already referencing in the configuration. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc

Comment: The connection pool size of your application has nothing to do with DBeaver. DBeaver being connected does not lease a connection from the connection pool in your application.